# C# наследование конструктора с необязательными параметрами

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

```
abstract class MyClass
{
  int Param1 {get; set;} 
  int Param2 {get; set;} 
  MyClass(int param1 = 4, int param2 = 10)
  {
  this.Param1 = param1;
  this.Param2 = param2;
  }
}

class Class1 : MyClass //переопределяю значения по-умолчанию
{
  int Param3 {get; set;} 
  Class1(int param1 = 4, int param2 = 10, int param3 = 2):base(param1, param2)
  {
  this.Param3 = param3;
  }
}
```

нужно сделать необязательные параметры в классе-наследнике не повторяя задание констант в параметрах
если при вызове параметр не задан, он берется из конструктора-родителя

похожее поведение можно достичь вручную  сделав необязательные параметры:

```
public Class1(int param1, int param2, int param3 = 2):base(param1, param2)
{
  this.Param3 = param3;
}
public Class1(int param1, int param3 = 2):base(param1: param1)
{
  this.Param3 = param3;
}
public Class1(int param3 = 2):base()
{
  this.Param3 = param3;
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72686/discussion-between-dgzargo-and-a-k).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72691/discussion-on-question-by-dgzargo-c----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы могли сделать параметры nullable типом:

```
abstract class MyClass
{
  public const int Param1Default = 4;
  public const int Param2Default = 10;

  int Param1 { get; set; }
  int Param2 { get; set; }

  protected MyClass(int? param1 = null, int? param2 = null)   
  {
    Param1 = param1 ?? Param1Default;
    Param2 = param2 ?? Param2Default;
  }
}

class Class1 : MyClass
{
  public const int Param3Default = 2;

  int Param3 { get; set; }

  public Class1(int? param1 = null, int? param2 = null, int? param3 = null)
  : base(param1, param2)
  {
     Param3 = param3 ?? Param3Default;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, ничего лучше такого не получится: https://ideone.com/R4imt8

```
abstract class MyClass
{
  public const int Param1Default = 4;
  public const int Param2Default = 10;

  int Param1 { get; set; }
  int Param2 { get; set; }

  public MyClass(int param1 = Param1Default, int param2 = Param2Default)
  {
    this.Param1 = param1;
    this.Param2 = param2;
  }
}

class Class1 : MyClass
{
  int Param3 { get; set; }

  public Class1
  (
    int param1 = MyClass.Param1Default,
    int param2 = MyClass.Param1Default,
    int param3 = 2
  )
  : base(param1, param2)
  {
    this.Param3 = param3;
  }
}
```

Comment: жаль что класс невозможно сделать константой. и придется лезть за значением внутрь базового класа